# How do I set the JVM heap size inside the Docker file?

Tags: java, docker

Like this:

```
ENTRYPOINT [ "java", "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Xms128m -Xmx512m", "-jar", "/p-tdh-message-steward-1.0.jar" ]
```

or like this:

```
ENTRYPOINT [ "java", "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom", "-Xms128m", "-Xmx512m", "-jar", "/p-tdh-message-steward-1.0.jar" ]
```

or some other way.  Sorry, my Google Foo has failed me.

Comment: The second solution seems correct.

Comment: Note that it's not 'the JVM size', but the heap size.

Comment: Bingo.  The second one worked.  Thanks @daniu for the info.I should have known that.